# How to add to and remove from system's environment variable "PATH"?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, registry, environment-variables

How do I **permanently** add the path to system's environment variable "PATH"?

I want to only add the path if it does not already exist.

Also I want to remove all paths that contain a folder name such as `\myprogram` whether it be:

`C:\path\to\myprogram\dist;` or `D:\another\path\to\myprogram\dist;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import _winreg as reg
import win32gui
import win32con


# read the value
key = reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment', 0, reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
# use this if you need to modify the system variable and if you have admin privileges
#key = reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment', 0, reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) 
try
    value, _ = reg.QueryValueEx(key, 'PATH')
except WindowsError:
    # in case the PATH variable is undefined
    value = ''

# modify it
value = ';'.join([s for s in value.split(';') if not r'\myprogram' in s])

# write it back
reg.SetValueEx(key, 'PATH', 0, reg.REG_EXPAND_SZ, value)
reg.CloseKey(key)

# notify the system about the changes
win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 'Environment')
```

Comment: Note that `win32gui` and `win32con` are contained in the package `pywin32`. At least in version 301 of pywin32, you need to do `import win32.win32gui as win32gui` instead of `import win32gui`.

Answer (score 13):

Here's something that does what you want which is similar to code in the [jaraco.windows](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jaraco.windows) project. And like it, **only uses built-in Python modules**—so doesn't require first downloading and installing the [pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32/214) extensions. **Plus it's Python 2.6+ and 3.x compatible and supports Unicode environment variables and values** (directory paths in this case).

Note that Windows administrator rights are required to change the permanent system-level environment variables.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, LPVOID
LRESULT = LPARAM  # synonymous
import os
import sys
try:
    import winreg
    unicode = str
except ImportError:
    import _winreg as winreg  # Python 2.x

class Environment(object):
    path = r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'
    hklm = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
    key = winreg.OpenKey(hklm, path, 0, winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WRITE)
    SendMessage = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW
    SendMessage.argtypes = HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPVOID
    SendMessage.restype = LRESULT
    HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF
    WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1A
    NO_DEFAULT_PROVIDED = object()

    def get(self, name, default=NO_DEFAULT_PROVIDED):
        try:
            value = winreg.QueryValueEx(self.key, name)[0]
        except WindowsError:
            if default is self.NO_DEFAULT_PROVIDED:
                raise ValueError("No such registry key", name)
            value = default
        return value

    def set(self, name, value):
        if value:
            winreg.SetValueEx(self.key, name, 0, winreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ, value)
        else:
            winreg.DeleteValue(self.key, name)
        self.notify()

    def notify(self):
        self.SendMessage(self.HWND_BROADCAST, self.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, u'Environment')

Environment = Environment()  # singletion - create instance

PATH_VAR = 'PATH'

def append_path_envvar(addpath):
    def canonical(path):
        path = unicode(path.upper().rstrip(os.sep))
        return winreg.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(path)  # Requires Python 2.6+
    canpath = canonical(addpath)
    curpath = Environment.get(PATH_VAR, '')
    if not any(canpath == subpath
                for subpath in canonical(curpath).split(os.pathsep)):
        Environment.set(PATH_VAR, os.pathsep.join((curpath, addpath)))

def remove_envvar_path(folder):
    """ Remove *all* paths in PATH_VAR that contain the folder path. """
    curpath = Environment.get(PATH_VAR, '')
    folder = folder.upper()
    keepers = [subpath for subpath in curpath.split(os.pathsep)
                if folder not in subpath.upper()]
    Environment.set(PATH_VAR, os.pathsep.join(keepers))
```

Sample usage:

```
print(Environment.get('path'))
append_path_envvar(r'C:\path\to\myprogram\dist')
append_path_envvar(r'D:\another\path\to\myprogram\dist')
print(Environment.get('path'))
remove_envvar_path(r'\myprogram')  # remove *both* added paths
print(Environment.get('path'))
```

Comment: Brilliant! It really answers the question the best way. Saved me 2 hours.

Comment: @Vasily: You're welcome. Note I just made a few minor improvements, if you're interested.

Comment: That is great. But what about user environment variables? You code can only remove env var from system, not user's ones.

Comment: @Gauthier: That's because the question is about modifying the system-level environment variables. I would assume the user's variables are simply stored somewhere else in the registry — probably `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a python package `pathtub` (I am the author), which can do the job. You can read the code and docs on [GitHub](https://github.com/np-8/pathtub).

#### Installing

```
pip install pathtub
```

#### Example usage

**Reading Path**

```py
from pathtub import get_path

# Getting path (can be 'process' (default), 'user' or 'machine')
user_path = get_path('user')

print(user_path)
# C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin;C:\Programs;C:\Programs\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin;C:\Programs\cloc;C:\Programs\fciv;C:\Python\Python37;C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\Python\Python37\Scripts;C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

**Adding to path**

```py
from pathtub import add_to_path
added = add_to_path(r'C:\Add this folder\to user path', mode='user')

print(added)
#True

# Adding duplicate entries is prevented
added = add_to_path(r'C:\Add this folder\to user path', mode='user')

print(added)
#False
```

**Removing from Path**

```py
removed = remove_from_path(r'C:\Add this folder\to user path', mode='user')

print(removed)
#True

# Removing non-existing folder just returns False
removed = remove_from_path(r'C:\Add this folder\to user path', mode='user')

print(removed)
#False
```

#### Requirements

Current implementation (v.1.1.2) uses Powershell for the permanent Path modifications. I have only tested this with newer (Python 3.7 and 3.8), but I guess it should work also on some older versions.

Answer (score 0):

I am inferring from the paths in your question that your are interested in doing this on the Windows platform.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653.aspx) describes the process:

> To programmatically add or modify system environment variables, add them to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment registry key, then broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message with lParam set to the string "Environment". This allows applications, such as the shell, to pick up your updates.

Comment: Do you know of any python libraries or simple scripts that take parameters and do the work for you?

Comment: win32xxx can do send message, and winreg does registry

Answer (score -1):

You should check [os.environ](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ). It's a dictionary that can be manipulated directly or via [os.putenv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.putenv):

> Set the environment variable named varname to the string value. Such
>   changes to the environment affect subprocesses started with
>   os.system(), popen() or fork() and execv().

Hence:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["PATH"] =  path_old + ":/tmp/hallo" 
>>> os.environ["PATH"] 
'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/tmp/hallo'
```

**[update]**

according [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/488475/342365) you can make them persistent via windows registry

Comment: You cannot "magically" make the changes to `os.environ` persistent using windows registry. You must write a concrete value there. You do not need to modify `os.environ` in order to do this. Moreover, you don't need to read it: the value of `os.environ["PATH"]` is composed of two values: user `PATH` and system `PATH`, which are stored in different registry keys. You should read a corresponding registry value instead.