# How to add a folder to the Windows PATH with Python?

Tags: python, windows, path, sys

I want to add a folder to the Windows PATH environment variable with Python. I tried these three code snippets but none worked:

```
os.environ['PATH'] += ";C:\my\folder"
```

and

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('C:\my\folder'))
```

and

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    sep = ';'
else:
    sep = ':'

os.environ['PATH'] += sep + r'"C:\my\folder"'
```

Comment: [about revision 3] OP used the sys module in some of his attempts, but it doesn't make the question related to that module.

Comment: `"\f"` is a form-feed character. You need to use a raw string. `sys.path` has *absolutely nothing* to do with the system `PATH` environment variable. The path separator is `os.pathsep`; do no hard code it in your script. Never use double quotes in `PATH`; CMD can handle quotes, but almost everything else uses `SearchPath`, which treats the quotes as literal characters.

Comment: This already has answers at [How to add to and remove from system's environment variable “PATH”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138014/how-to-add-to-and-remove-from-systems-environment-variable-path) and [Change %PATH% from Python Script (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951885/change-path-from-python-script-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

`os.environ['PATH'] += R";C:\my\folder"`

Answer (score 0):

The Windows command for *permanently* changing the path is

```
setx /M path "%path%;C:\my\folder"
```

You can execute arbitrary shell commands via Python with `os.system`

```
import os
os.system('setx /M path "%path%;C:\my\folder"')
```

Note:

You need to run this with elevated privileges.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: Thank You! how to require it to run as administrator

Comment: Never use setx.exe to change `PATH`. It's wrong in at least two seriously bad ways. (1) It hard codes the current value of named variables such as `%UserProfile%`. (2) `PATH` consists of a system value and a per-user value that get concatenated at load time, and using setx.exe with the already concatenated value sets the per-user component in the system component, which will increasingly make a mess of `PATH` every time you do this.

Comment: so how to add to PATH?