# What is the use of os.environ?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

Is `os.environ` is same as changing environmental variables from settings in Windows?

```
Import os
os.environ[‘variable_name’] = [‘value’]
```

I tried above to change environment variable, I ran above code from `pythonshell` and checked my environment variable from Windows settings. I didn’t see that value.

Is this approach right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set an environment variable from Python permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657686/is-it-possible-to-set-an-environment-variable-from-python-permanently)

Comment: `os.environ` is, of course, very useful for getting values FROM the environment.  Changing `os.environ` changes a variable during the execution of your process, and in any new processes that you create.  Your environment is deleted when your program ends.

Comment: You can modify system environment variables on Windows by changing the registry through the `winreg` module (if your script can be run with administrative privileges). See [How to add to and remove from system's environment variable “PATH”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138014/how-to-add-to-and-remove-from-systems-environment-variable-path) for an example.

Comment: @RandomDavis: This question is not a duplicate of that linked one IMO.