# Setting and using environment variables via pipes in linux

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, pipe

How do I set environment variables in one script and after piping the output to another script, I need certain environment variable to be set in first script and used in second script.

I am using python scripts.

```
python script1.py | python script2.py
```

in `script1.py` , I am doing

```
os.environ["some_key"] = some_value
```

and in `script2.py` , I am trying to read it as

```
saved_value = os.environ["some_key"]
```

When I try to run the above scripts as mentioned above,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script2.py", line 11, in <module>
    filename = os.environ["some_key"]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
```

Is there anyway this can be corrected ? I specifically need it to be read from `os.environ["some_key"]` in `script2.py` as that file is part of bigger framework and cant change it. I have flexibility with with `script1.py`

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488366/how-do-i-make-environment-variable-changes-stick-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to set environment variables of another process - *unless you launch it yourself*.

If you can, consider changing `script1` to launch `script2` directly using `subprocess.Popen`, and supply the `env` argument.

If you can't do this, you'll need to change the parent process (probably the bash script that launchs the scripts) to, somehow, receive the desired variable from `script1` and set it when launching script2.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to alter the environment of a sibling process.

You can use a convoluted construct like the one below:

```
{ export some_key=$(python script1.py) ; } |& python script2.py
```

where `script1.py` outputs the environment variable to `stdout` and writes the stuff to be fed to `script2.py` to `stderr`. This will only allow setting one environment variable though.

Example:

```
$ cat script1.py 
import sys
print "some_env_value"
sys.stderr.write("some_piped_value\n")
$ cat script2.py 
import os
import sys

print "Passed through enviroment:", os.environ["some_key"]
print "Passed through stdin:",

for line in sys.stdin:
        print line
```

Result:

```
$ { export some_key=$(python script1.py) ; } |& python script2.py
Passed through enviroment: some_env_value2
Passed through stdin: some_piped_value
```