# How to call python through subprocess.call

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to run a script from python subprocess.

```
subprocess.call('set APPID=Testforscannedpdf',shell=True)
subprocess.call('set PWD=XXXXXXXXXXXX',shell=True)
subprocess.call('C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python.exe C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Parsing\\COF.pdf C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Parsing\\pdf_conv.py C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Parsing\\out\\outputs.txt',shell=True)
```

When I run it directly on Anaconda Prompt/command prompt I am able to run it. But when I am trying run it through subprocess I am unable to get the output. It always gives output as 1.

I know the error is in the 3rd 'subprocess.call' statement because of the spaces between arguments. But I unable to find a fix for it. I also tried passing the arguments in a list in 'subprocess.Popen' but no results again.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! Looks like there are some duplicated questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string ; hope it hepls

Comment: Not sure how it is related to my answer. I have already tried this 'import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/Desktop/Parsing')                       subprocess.call('set APPID=Testforscannedpdf',shell=True)
subprocess.call('set PWD=XXXXXXX',shell=True)
subprocess.call(["python","pdf_conv.py","COF.pdf","outputs.txt"])' but no output

Comment: Have you tried `Popen'?` `p = subprocess.Popen(["python","pdf_conv.py","COF.pdf","outputs.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` then `out, err = p.communicate()`?

Comment: It looks as if you're trying to call `python.exe` with three arguments which are respectively the paths to a PDF file, a Python script and a text file. Shouldn't the Python script be the first one?

Comment: This is what I am following 'https://ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start-guide/python-ocr-sdk/'  and its working when I am writing the same statements directly in command prompt/Anaconda prompt.

Comment: @MikhailStepanov Yup tried this but not working. This is what i am getting 'b'Uploading..\r\n'' That means it fails at uploading part i.e., COF.pdf

Comment: The `subprocess` module, like its name reveals, creates a subprocess, changes its environment, and eventually quits. The parent Python process has no idea, and generally shouldn't care about or be affected by what the subprocess does to its own environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make environment variable changes stick in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488366/how-do-i-make-environment-variable-changes-stick-in-python)

Comment: @MikhailStepanov         err
Out[72]: b"Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'\n\nCurrent thread 0x00002ca4 (most recent call first):\n"

Comment: I updated [my answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188) with more details for this particular case.  This is a common FAQ, and definitely a duplicate.

Comment: @tripleee How should i apply in my case.Sorry, but I am unable to replicate it for my scenario with 2 environment variables i.e., APPID and PWD

Comment: This is what I did   :-      import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/Desktop/Parsing')
subprocess.run(["python.exe","pdf_conv.py","COF.pdf","outputs.txt"],shell=True,env={'APPID':'Testforscannedpdf','PWD':'xxxxxxx' })    Output is:
Out[86]: CompletedProcess(args=['python.exe', 'pdf_conv.py', 'COF.pdf', 'outputs.txt'], returncode=3221225781)

Comment: You can't have `shell=True` if the first argument is not a string. I'm guessing there might be additional problems, which could be simply because you are using Windows.