# Environment variable gets removed immediately after it is set Python

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have this simple environment set script in Python:

```
import os
os.environ['API_USER'] = 'SuperUser'
os.environ['API_PASSWORD'] = 'SuperPass'

USER = os.environ.get('API_USER')
PASSWORD = os.environ.get('API_PASSWORD')

print(USER)
print(PASSWORD)
```

When I run it I get this:

```
SuperUser
SuperPass
```

So far OK, but when I comment out two lines where I set user and pass and run it again, I get this:

```
None
None
```

Why those two environment variable are removed and are not saved? I was wondering, that once I set some environment variable, I can use it again later without setting it again (until I delete them), right?
What is wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: If I remember it correctly, Environment variables set inside a process are available only inside the same process. If you want to make these environment variables across process, I think you need to use SETX, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488366/how-do-i-make-environment-variable-changes-stick-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only setting the environment variable for that specific running Python process.  Once the process exits, the variable ceases to exist.  It appears you cannot set a persistent environment variable from Python, as is described here:

[Why can't environmental variables set in python persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716011/why-cant-environmental-variables-set-in-python-persist)

It looks like you'll need to shell execute whatever variable you want to persist, as is described in the second answer to the above questions, like so:

```
import pipes
import random
r = random.randint(1,100)
print("export BLAHBLAH=%s" % (pipes.quote(str(r))))
```

*Edit:*

As per @SuperStormer's comment below--they are correct--this solution is Unix/Mac specifc.  If you need to accomplish the same thing on Windows you would utilize `setx` like so (this would set the variable for only current user, you need to add a `/m` switch on the end to set for the local machine):

```
import pipes
import random
r = random.randint(1,100)
print("setx BLAHBLAH %s" % (pipes.quote(str(r))))
```

Comment: pipes -> shlex(that's where pipes imports quote from anyways). Note that this solution is unix-specific, windows uses setx instead.