# python set windows environment parameters persistent

Tags: python, windows

I would like to set environment parameters using python in windows 11.
Using commands like:

```
import os
os.environ['USER'] = 'username'
print(os.environ['USER'])
```

will print *username*. Nether the less, once I close the window. The set environment parameters dissipated. It seems I need something like *SETX* command in windows. I found the article [how do I make environment variable changes stick in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488366/how-do-i-make-environment-variable-changes-stick-in-python). Nether the less, they use there the windows command.

Are there python commands as well to do the same? instead of sending *subprocess* or *os.system* commands.

Answer (score 0):

You basically answered the question yourself with the link you provided.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)

```
This mapping is captured the first time the os module is imported
```

This is a bit of an interpretation from me, but that means os.environ is not a reference to the environment variable, but a copy of them in your Python interpreter,which seems to be validated a bit further in the doc':

```
Changes to the environment made after this time are not reflected in os.environ
```

While I do not really understand while you would want a program to modify your environment variables (a bit risky, no ?), you should probably go with the solution you provided in your question.